# Error with LaTeX IET template

Tags: templates

```
\documentclass{cta-author}

\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{diagbox}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{bibtex}




\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}{}
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}{}
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}{}

\begin{document}

\bibliographystyle{iet} 
\bibliography{aaa}

\cite{boulkenafet2017face}
```

Why i am getting error while running the above code in texmaker?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Where did you get the template (link)? What error do you get?